# Find a unit vector and the rate of change

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Could anyone help me answer this question? Or point me in the right direction?

Find a unit vector in the direction in which f increases most rapidly at P and find the rate of change of f at p in that direction.

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{\frac{xy}{x+y}}; \qquad P(1,1)$$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdL6Q.png

Comment: Are you familiar with the gradient?

Answer (score 1):

A vector in the direction of most change is $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$. Divide by its length to find a unit vector.

Add the unit vector to P and evaluate f to find the rate of change.